# processing Xnode with Linq efficiently

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I have xml Node with following format. This node must be converted to userdefined type that is each node must convert to object of say MyClass

```
class MyClass
{
  public string tag1Id {get;set;}
  public int tag3Val {get;set;}
  public string tag3Id {get;set;}
  public int tag5Val {get;set;}
  public string tag5Id {get;set;}
  public DataTime tag7Val {get;set;}

}

  <tag1 id="id1">
     <tag2>
       <tag3 id="id3">10</tag3>
       <tag4>
        <tag5 id="id5">20</tag5>
       </tag4>
     </tag2>
     <tag6>
      <tag7>2010-12-31</tag7>
     </tag6>
    </tag1>
```

I am new to linq, Can it be done using linq. Requirement is xmlseralization should not be used :(
Is there any other approach by which this scenario can be handled easily?

Comment: What is the point of this xml?  The names are horrible.  If the xml being used isn't from legacy code, change it so it has meaning, or it will be impossible to debug/maintain/understand years from now if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it cannot be done.

There must be a conversion done somewhere due to the business logic plumbing to go to the specific properties from the exacting node ids/locations.

What can be done is to code a constructor which takes in the node and populates the properties accordingly. Linq can then be used to enumerate over the nodes and create a new projection of the class elements via select such as:

```
     string data = @"
<tags>
  <tag id=""id1""> 
     <tag2> 
       <tag3 id=""id3"">10</tag3> 
       <tag4> 
        <tag5 id=""id5"">20</tag5> 
       </tag4> 
     </tag2> 
     <tag6> 
      <tag7>2010-12-31</tag7> 
     </tag6> 
    </tag> 
</tags>
    ";
var xml = XDocument.Parse(data);

    var classes = xml.Descendants( "tag1" )
                     .Select( nd => new MyClass( nd ) );
```